# Можно ли писать каким-нибудь OutputStream в файл, который отдаётся клиенту на лету

Tags: java, http

**Дано:** большой поток данных, которые надо отдать клиенту в веб-интерфейсе файлом.

**Условие:** данных много, в памяти держать нельзя, писать в файловую систему тоже нежелательно.

**Вопрос:** можно ли писать файл клиенту потоком или writer'ом на лету, как будто бы он просто скачивает файлик с сервера?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, можно.

см [getWriter](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29) и [getOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream%28%29). Более того, такой способ является основным для HTTP.

**UPD**

Поскольку простейший вопрос каким-то непостижимым для меня способом получил два голоса, то видимо стоит добавить к ответу краткий пример. Хотя, я в недоумении, откуда взялся такой странный и при этом популярный вопрос, относящийся к самым основам веб-разработки на Java. Если у вас на руках сервлет, то вы из него пишете что хотите и в любом количестве.

```
@WebServlet(name = "MyServlet", urlPatterns = "/my-servlet-path")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // ...
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

        // здесь пишем в поток что хотим сколько угодно, пока принимающая сторона не лопнет

    }
}
```

Comment: Вопросик:

каким образом, не записывая в файл (или память), сервер сформирует "Content-Length: ... " в заголовке ответа ?

Comment: Никаким. Сервер выставит режим chuned и будет писать чанками.